# My best friend passed away. He encrypted his computer but did not tell her what the key ring password was

Tags: gnome

How do I get into the computer and change the password

Comment: You can't... One way to bypass a password is to install Linux on another drive and then mount the old drives. Then you have full access. But if the data is encrypted, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

If the computer is indeed running Ubuntu, with the home directory encrypted (option suggested, during install), then breaking the password (forcing to a known value) will let you access the computer but will NOT give access to the encrypted content.

*This is simply to protect the contents from exposure, if the computer is ever compromised or lost.*

For there to be a conventient way around this would be a serious design flaw (much like Windows 7/8/10, *sans* BitLocker).

---

Not sure what can be done to assist you ..

**What further details can you provide?**

- version of Ubuntu, type of encryption;
- loss to next-of-kin/society, if data not recovered;
- what backups exist (are they also encrypted);
- etc. ..